# Why is no output displayed?

Tags: delphi

I started learning classes and objects programming today. There is code in the handbook that I must copy to run and save. I need to create a class(TLine) and use that class for instantiating an object.

Problem : No output is displayed in my RichEdit component. I copied the code exactly from the book to delphi, but no output is displayed.

How the output should look: "**********"

My class:

```
unit Lines_U;

interface

uses
Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms,
Dialogs;

Type
  TLine = Class
Public
  fSize : integer;
  fPattern : char;

public
   Constructor Create;
   Procedure Draw(Var line: string);
end;

implementation

{ TLine }

Constructor TLine.Create;
begin
   fSize := 10;
   fPattern := '*';
end;

Procedure TLine.Draw(Var line: string);
Var
loop : integer;
begin
    for loop := 1 to fSize do
    begin
    line := line + fPattern;
    end;
end;
end.
```

Code for instantiating the Object of the TLine Class:

```
unit UseLine_U;

interface

uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms,
  Dialogs, Lines_U, StdCtrls, ComCtrls;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    redOut: TRichEdit;
    Procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;
  line : TLine;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

Procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
Var tempLine : string;
begin
   line := TLine.Create;
   line.Draw(tempLine);
   redOut.Lines.Add(tempLine);
end;
end.
```

Comment: This question is off topic on this site because the code in the question does not behave as you describe

Comment: I doesn't give me any output, any idea why this might be?

Comment: That is not so. That code does not behave the way you describe. Your code is different.

Comment: Put a debugger breakpoint on the line "line := TLine.Create;" and run your application.  Does the debugger stop on the breakpoint?

Comment: Yeah, that's probably it @MartynA, the event is not hooked up

Comment: Did you use Delphi IDE to create `FormCreate` handler or "just copied" it?

Comment: @MartinA the debugger is active on that line.

Comment: So you need to select the form in the designer, go to the object inspector, open the events page, and set the `OnCreate` event to `FormCreate`. Your code leaks the `TLine` instance by the way and you need to stop using global variables like that. Whoever is teaching you is doing it badly.

Comment: Thanks everyone. @David Heffernan, I did what you said and it works fine now.

Comment: So your previous comment is not correct, the debugger would not have been breaking on that line.

Comment: I thought it did, my bad.

Comment: Please feel free to ask in a comment if there's anything in my answer that you don't understand (or disagree with :-).

Comment: Is the handbook you mentioned something that your instructor wrote or is it publicly available?  I'm asking because the code seems to be of such poor quality that it is really doing students a disservice to base their learning of Delphi on it.

Comment: It is publicly available, but the book states this at the methods, "We will change this later". It's just temporary

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason your code is not running is that your event handler `Form1.FormCreate` is not linked to the `OnCreate` event. Restore the link in the object inspector.

**About event handlers**
Never write event handlers (all those procedures starting with `On...`) manually. Always use the `Object inspector` to create them.

[image]

If you double click on an event, Delphi will create a code template for you that you can fill with data.
Make sure your event handlers are filled in the object inspector. If not they will not work (as you've seen).
If you want to **remove** an event handler **do not** remove it in the object inspector, but reduce the code inside the event handling procedure back to the empty template.
Delphi will see that it is empty and remove it on the next compile.

**About your code**
Other than the missing link there is nothing wrong with your code. It runs just fine.
There are a few style issues though, these have no bearing on the operation, but are important none the less.

Here's how I would rewrite your code.

```
unit Lines_U;

interface

//only import units that you actually use.    

type  //please type reserved words in all lowercase, this is Pascal not VB.
  TLine = class
  private //make data members private.
    fSize : integer;
    fPattern : char;
  public
    constructor Create;
    procedure Draw(var line: string);
    property Size: integer read fSize write fSize; //Use properties to expose data members.
    property Pattern: char read fPattern write fPattern;   
  end;

implementation

{ TLine }

constructor TLine.Create;
begin
  inherited; //make the inherited call in your constructor explicit.
  fSize := 10;
  fPattern := '*';
end;

procedure TLine.Draw(var line: string);
//var
  //loop : integer; //use consistent indentation 
begin
  //Changing a string ten times in a row is inefficient.
  //try to do your changes all at once.
  //for loop := 1 to fSize do begin
  //  line := line + fPattern;
  //end;
  Line:= Line + StringOfChar(fPattern, fSize); 
end;

end.
```

Your form:

```
unit UseLine_U;

interface

uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms,
  Dialogs, StdCtrls, ComCtrls, Lines_U;  
  //put your own unit last, to prevent name clashes with built in classes and functions.


type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    //note that the {nothing} line is really **published**. 
    //And data members should be private
    //Line : TLine;  //Line should be private.
    RedOut: TRichEdit;
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
  private
    //Prefix all private data with `F` for Field.
    FLine: TLine;  //Line should be a item in the form, not a global var.
  public
    property Line: TLine read FLine; //read only access to line.
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var 
  tempLine : string;
  i: integer;
begin
  //tempLine:= '';  //local variables should be initialized.
  //However strings are always initialized to '', because they are managed types.
  //everything else will contain random data unless you fill it!
  FLine := TLine.Create;
  Line.Draw(tempLine);
  i:= 0;  //init i, otherwise it will be random!
  while i < 5 do begin  //always use `begin-end` in loops, never a naked `do`
    RedOut.Lines.Add(tempLine);
    i:= i + 1;
  end; {while}  //I like to annotate my loop `end`s, but that's just me.
  FreeAndNil(FLine);   //Dispose of TLine when you're done with it.
end;

end.
```

I can think of other things, but I don't want to overload you.

Comment: "Never write event handlers (all those procedures starting with On...) manually. Always use the Object inspector to create them." I write them manually all the time... Well, then again, I know better than to leave it unlinked though.

Comment: FWIW, as you can see in his example, `TForm1.FormCreate` and all other event *handlers*, i.e. the methods (procedures, functions), do not start with "On". The *events* have names starting with "On", though. IIRC, in .NET, this is exactly the other way around.